# Mod of power 2 on bitwise operators?

Tags: c, math, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

1. How does mod of power of 2 work on only lower order bits of a binary number (`1011000111011010`)?
2. What is this number mod 2 to power 0, 2 to power 4?
3. What does power of 2 have to do with the modulo operator? Does it hold a special property?
4. Can someone give me an example?

The instructor says "When you take something mod to power of 2 you just take its lower order bits". I was too afraid to ask what he meant =)

Comment: Why don't you try a few example calculations by hand, then you'll see what happens.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

He meant that taking `number mod 2^n` is equivalent to stripping off all but the `n` lowest-order *(right-most)* bits of `number`.

For example, if n == 2,

```
number      number mod 4
00000001      00000001
00000010      00000010
00000011      00000011
00000100      00000000
00000101      00000001
00000110      00000010
00000111      00000011
00001000      00000000
00001001      00000001
etc.
```

So in other words, `number mod 4` is the same as `number & 00000011` (where `&` means bitwise-and)

---

Note that this works exactly the same in base-10:  `number mod 10` gives you the last digit of the number in base-10, `number mod 100` gives you the last two digits, etc.

Comment: This is only the case when all operands are positive! Depending on the language the behavior will differ. For instance in C, `-5 % 4 == -1` despite the fact that in algebra we usually expect that `-5 mod 4` is 3 (and in C: `-5 & (4 - 1) == 3`. This means for instance that a compiler will not optimize a literal `% 4` with a `&` if the left operand is not unsigned.

Comment: @calandoa: We are discussing binary as a number system here, not bit-encoding of numbers.  `-5`, for instance, is written `-101`.

Comment: @BlueRaja: Of course we are talking about bit encoding : `&` is not defined for mathematical `-`. I guess your remark is more "we are not talking about negative numbers". Maybe we are not, but this is not clear in the question nor in your answer, so I made it clearer.

Comment: Do you thing at something like `number MOD 256` <=> `(number & (0xFF00)) >> 8` (for 2^8 = 256)

Answer (score 45):

What he means is that :

```
x modulo y = (x & (y − 1))
```

When y is a power of 2.

Example:

```
0110010110 (406) modulo
0001000000 (64)  =
0000010110 (22)
^^^^<- ignore these bits
```

Using your example now :

```
1011000111011010 (45530) modulo
0000000000000001 (2 power 0) =
0000000000000000 (0)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^<- ignore these bits

1011000111011010 (45530) modulo
0000000000010000 (2 power 4) =
0000000000001010 (10)
^^^^^^^^^^^^<- ignore these bits
```

Answer (score 17):

Consider when you take a number modulo 10. If you do that, you just get the last digit of the number.

```
  334 % 10 = 4
  12345 % 10 = 5
```

Likewise if you take a number modulo 100, you just get the last two digits.

```
  334 % 100 = 34
  12345 % 100 = 45
```

So you can get the modulo of a power of two by looking at its last digits in binary. That's the same as doing a bitwise and.

Comment: Would that hold for powers of 2 as well ? 54 % 32 which is 2^5 gives 22.

Comment: Popo: Yes. The number of bits at the end is determined by which power of two you're using. As described by Cicada, you would calculate it as 54 & (32-1).

Answer (score 7):

Modulo in general returns the remainder of a value after division. So `x mod 4`, for example, returns 0, 1, 2 or 3 depending on x. These possible values can be represented using two bits in binary (00, 01, 10, 11) - another way to do `x mod 4` is to simply set all the bits to zero in x except the last two ones.

Example:

```
      x = 10101010110101110
x mod 4 = 00000000000000010
```

Answer (score 4):

Answering your specific questions:

1. mod is a remainder operator.  If applied to a series of numbers x in 0, 1, ..., then x mod n will be 0, 1, ..., n-1, 0, 1, ..., n-1, ad infinitum.  When your modulus n is a power of 2, then x mod n will count up in binary from 0 to n-1, back to 0, to n-1, etc; for modulus n that looks like binary 01xxxxx, x mod n will cycle through every of those low-order bits xxxxx.
2. binary 1011000111011010 mod 1 is 0 (mod 2^0 yields the last zero bits; everything mod 1 is zero).  binary 1011000111011010 mod binary 10000 is 1010 (mod 2^4 yields the last four bits).
3. Division and remainder of binary number by powers of two is particularly efficient because it's just shifting and masking; mathematically it's nothing special.
4. Example: See answer to question 2.